# Need help in forming validation rule

Tags: validation-rule

I have to two fields Payment status and manager status
So have to create a validation rule where if Manager status is Blank and payment status is closed then block payment status update.

My formula is
`AND(ISPICKVAL(Manager_Status,''), ISPICKVAL(Payment_status,'Resolved'),ISCHANGED(Payment_status))`

But my formula is not working and no validation giving while saving the change

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. Without this, your question is likely to be closed without answer.

Comment: give more detais: what kind of error do you get and what is your context of getting the error. That would help others reproduce your case

Comment: Does your formula use the `__c` for custom fields API names?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a validation rule like
AND(
ISBLANK(Manager_Status__c),
ISPICKVAL(Payment_Status__c, "Closed")
)

considering Manager_Status__c is text and Payment_Status__c is picklist field .

If both are picklist you can use
AND(
ISPICKVAL(Manager_Status__c, ""),
ISPICKVAL(payment_Status__c, "Closed")
)

Comment: This has not worked

Answer (score -1):

Try this, here Manager_Status__c and Payment_Status__c are as picklist fields

```
AND( ISBLANK(  TEXT( Manager_Status__c ) ) ,
 NOT( ISPICKVAL( Payment_Status__c , "Closed") ) 
)
```

Comment: If you want it to run only when updating the record then use this --------
```
AND( ISBLANK(  TEXT( Manager_Status__c ) ) ,
 NOT( ISPICKVAL( Payment_Status__c , "Closed") ) ,
 NOT( ISNEW() ) 
)
```